# Can an OLEobjects textbox be Visible but not editable?

Tags: vba

I have certain command buttons on a WorkSheet that I want hidden until a password is entered.
I do this by having an OLEobjects textbox cover them.
The textbox is called "HideButtons" and, when visible, covers certain command buttons.
The textbox has no border and is the same colour as the background.
To see the command buttons, a password is entered and I change the textbox visibility to False.

```
`ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("HideButtons").Visible = True
 ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("HideButtons").Visible = False`
```

The WorkSheet is protected to ensure users only have access to certain cells and buttons.
When 'HideButtons' is visible, and the command buttons beneath it are hidden 'HideButtons' can still have text entered in to it.
Is there any way I can prevent users entering text into the 'HideButtons' textbox?

Comment: What if you change its `Enabled` property to false?

Comment: I suppose that the text box you need to be locked is not the one where the password to be inputted. If my supposition is correct, why don't you simple make the buttons visible (or  not) and you need a text box control to cover them? Is it something I missed?